# Start an activity from a ListView, get extra data from a string and add a picture into a layout

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-intent

The app I am creating is a simple questions and answers app. The questions (in a string array) are in a custom listView.

What I would like to happen is that when I click on a question it takes me to one layout and the corresponding answer (from a string array) will appear in relation to the question clicked i.e. if question 3 was clicked answer 3 will appear. Additionally a different picture will appear underneath each answer, e.g. pic1, pic2, pic3.
I believe the Main class should implement an onItemClickListener and use switch/case. I think I should be using intent extras but can't find how to write the code for this process to happen.

---

*Questions string array:*

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="questions">
        <item >q1</item>
        <item >q2</item>
        <item >q3</item>
    </string-array> 
</resources>
```

---

*main layout for listView questions:*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Questions" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

list_View layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

*Main java class:*

> public class Main extends ListActivity {
>
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>                 setContentView(R.layout.main);
>
> ```
>   setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
>           R.id.textView1, getResources()
>                   .getStringArray(R.array.questions)));   }
> ```
>
> private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
>
> ```
>   public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
>           String[] strings) {             
>               super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
>
>   }
>
>   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>
>       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
> ```
>
> getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);            View row =
>   inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);          String[] items
>   = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
>
> ```
>       TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
>       tv.setText(items[position]);
>
>       return row;         }   }
> ```
>
> }

---

*Answers string array*

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="answers">
        <item>a1</item>
        <item>a2</item>
        <item>a3</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

---

*answer layout*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

*Answer class*

```
public class Answer extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.answer);
    }
}
```

---

Comment: please put some efforts for searching before asking question.

Comment: I have done a lot a searching and can not get my head around this. I will keep trying. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can implement the onclick listener for the view "row" inside the getview method and pass the required question detail in the extras to your answer activity.

Add extra to intent:

```
yourintent.putExtra("myquestionref","Question 1");
```

Getting the extra informations from the intent:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("myquestionref");
```

[Android Intent extra sample](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html)

Please let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I am still unsure of where to put this code but I will keep trying and looking around. Cheers